# Best way to use spreadsheet RegEx to extract text and numbers and replace with the formatting?

Tags: regex, replace, google-sheets, extract

I'm currently working on a non profit project where I need to reformat the way the data in the rows displays.

At the moment, this is how the row data looks:

```
Save The Children (Donation)|10.00{0}{2}
```

And I need it to output like this instead:

```
donation_id:save_children|quantity:1|total:10.00
```

**The first problem** is sometimes there's multiple items within the row:

```
Save The Children (Donation)|10.00{0}{2} / Save The Forrest|15.50{0}{2}
```

In which case it would need to be separated by a semicolon:

```
donation_id:save_children|quantity:1|total:10.00;donation_id:save_forrest|quantity:1|total:15.50
```

**The second problem** is, we have 9 donation variables/causes, each needing to convert the output to a different "donation_id".

So every time it finds:

*Save the Children*, it needs to convert to: *donation_id:save_children*

*Save the Forrest*, to, *donation_id:save_forrest*

*Save the Animals*, to, *donation_id:save_animals*

And so forth.

And **the third problem** is that the donation amounts are variable (as people donate whatever they wish), so the "total:" dollar value that we ouput will often be different.

How would I go about doing this with the regex?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use below regex

```
(Save) The (Children|Forrest|Animals).*?\|([0-9]+\.[0-9]+)\{0\}\{2\}([\s\/]+)?
```

substitution/replace with

```
donation_id:$1_$2|quantity:1|total:$3;
```

When I test for

```
Save The Children (Donation)|10.00{0}{2} / Save The Forrest|15.50{0}{2}
```

Output is

```
donation_id:Save_Children|quantity:1|total:10.00;donation_id:Save_Forrest|quantity:1|total:15.50;
```

[Test it online!](https://regex101.com/r/1J77Cf/1)